# Chamar banco de dados em outra activity

Tags: android

Boa tarde, criei um aplicativo que conta o numero de gols e o nome do time, e no aplicativo tem um botão que se chama resultado (no menu) que abre outra activity result, que possui uma área para colocar o nome do time e manda pesquisar, nisso ele mostra o resultado e o nome do time... só que o problema é que não sei como chamar o banco de dados na outra activity, fiz o banco de dados, e fiz a chamada listar para mostrar o resultado mas precisaria chamar na outra activity e quando clicar no botão ele chama esse banco de dados.

primeira tela Código:

```
public class FutebolSimples extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imgButton_1, imgButton_2;
    private Button vermelho, amarelo;
    private TextView txt_valor1, txt_valor2;
    private EditText nomeTime1, nomeTime2;
    private int contador = 0;
    private int contador1 = 0;
    long tempoPausado = 0;

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_futebol_simples);

        imgButton_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_1);
        imgButton_2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_2);
        reloginho = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        txt_valor1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor1);
        txt_valor2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor2);
        nomeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbl_time1);
        nomeTime2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbl_time2);
        vermelho = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnvermelho);
        amarelo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAmarelo);

        imgButton_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contador++;
                txt_valor1.setText(" " + contador);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Goooool!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        imgButton_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contador1++;
                txt_valor2.setText(" " + contador1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Goooool!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Resultado", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS futebol (TimeOne VARCHAR, TimeTwo VARCHAR, FinalOne INT, FinalTwo INT);");

    }


    public void saveR (View view){

        if(txt_valor1.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || txt_valor2.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || nomeTime1.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || nomeTime2.toString().trim().length()==0 || vermelho.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || amarelo.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor inicia uma partida!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        }

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO futebol VALUES('"+txt_valor1.getText()+"','"+txt_valor2.getText()+"','"+nomeTime1.getText()+"','"+nomeTime2.getText()+"','"+vermelho.getText()+"','"+amarelo.getText()+"');");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Partida Salva", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void listar (View view){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM futebol", null);

        if (c.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro na pesquisa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (c.moveToFirst()) {

            buffer.append("Nome: "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resultado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.salvar) {

            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.result) {
            Intent mostrarResul = new Intent(this, ResultSimples.class);
            startActivity(mostrarResul);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

OBS: a criação do banco esta na mesma activity no oncreate bundle....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode passar o dado por parametro ou acessar o banco da outra activity:

é só chamar a mesma tabela

Use os mesmos comandos

```
 db = openOrCreateDatabase("Resultado", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS futebol (TimeOne VARCHAR, TimeTwo VARCHAR, FinalOne INT, FinalTwo INT);");

}


public void saveR (View view){

    if(txt_valor1.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || txt_valor2.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || nomeTime1.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || nomeTime2.toString().trim().length()==0 || vermelho.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || amarelo.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor inicia uma partida!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    }

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO futebol VALUES('"+txt_valor1.getText()+"','"+txt_valor2.getText()+"','"+nomeTime1.getText()+"','"+nomeTime2.getText()+"','"+vermelho.getText()+"','"+amarelo.getText()+"');");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Partida Salva", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void listar (View view){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM futebol", null);

    if (c.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro na pesquisa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToFirst()) {

        buffer.append("Nome: "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resultado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, quando vai abrir activity ele mostra uma mensagem de erro "o aplicativo parou de funcionar" por que está acontecendo isso? foi depois de colocar o banco de dados....

Comment: Na segunda activity? manda o codigo dela tbm, a primeira isoladamente roda né

Comment: Já consegui aqui valeu pela ajuda ....